# How to monitor unexpected shutdowns of my application on windows

Tags: python, monitoring, shutdown

I have an executable that i created in python.
This executable is supposed to always run in the background silently and send information to the server.
I distribute this executable to many clients.
Sometimes the server stops receiving information from a client for some unexpected reason.
I would assume that the executable stopped running for some reason on the clients computer.
I would like to monitor why I have unexpected shutdowns on the executable.
How should i monitor these unexpected shutdowns?
A solution using windows service for me is not acceptable because of administrative issues for some of the clients.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer to a previous question:
https://superuser.com/questions/461546/run-a-python-script-in-background-and-restart-it-on-crash

Basically it says:

```
#!/bin/bash   
until myscript.py; do   
    echo "'myscript.py' crashed with exit code $?. Restarting..." >&2   
    sleep 1   
done
```

Then just start the monitor script in background:

nohup monitor.sh &
end quote

If these scripts are running on remote machines adjust the monitor script to send yourself an email, notifying you of the error.

Comment: I doubt it, you didn't mention windows but there will be a windows equivalent, so the hunt is on.

Comment: A quick dig around suggests that you would have to run it as a windows service but I know very little about windows, so I'm not qualified to suggest any more than that.

Comment: Not an option for me because my application works for both administrative and non-administrative clients, whereas a windows service could only be used by administrative users.

Comment: @yuval Mention that in your question, it's important.

Comment: @yuval Have you looked at the "Start" command. I'm led to believe that that might help you.